# Pegando Imagem de uma website externa e colocar numa <div>

Tags: div, img

Boa tarde, ainda sou novo nesse ramo, mas tem como pegar uma imagem de um site externo e colocar na minha pagina? eu pesquisei algumas funções tipo o .load() ajax ou em php com file_get_contents()
eu poderia pegar a imagem pelo link direto só que como a imagem vai mudando não daria certo. Essa imagem pertence a uma div talvez se eu conseguir trazer essa div para o meu html, teria como colocar só a url: http://exemple.com e nesse site pegar só aquela img com uma id especifica?

Comment: "Acho" que dá pra fazer isso com uma chamada ajax, mas isso me soa muito como "gambiarra". Teria que exibir a resposta mapeando os elementos 1 a 1 até chegar nessa tal imagem.

Comment: Tem sim, mas qual é o site e qual div está a imagem?